# MongoDB improve $not & $elemMatch performance

Tags: mongodb

Let's say the DB contains tens of thousands of docs having the following structure

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId("5ef053e819aaa00013a2bd69"),
  approvers: [
    {
      type: "ONE",
      details: {
        name: "NameOne",
        surname: "SurnameOne"
      }
    },
    {
      type: "TWO",
      details: {
        name: "NameTwo",
        surname: "SurnameTwo"
      }
    },
    {
      type: "THREE",
      // details field is missing
    }

  ]
}
```

I need to select only such docs where there's **no** approver of type "TWO" or "ONE" or the approver has missing **details**

I had an idea to use `$not` in a combination with `$elemMatch`:

```json
{
  $or: [
    {
      "approvers.type": {
        $not: {
          $in: ["ONE", "TWO"]
        }
      }
    }, 
   {
      approvers: {
        $not: {
          $elemMatch: {
            type: { $in: ["ONE", "TWO"]},
            details: {$exists: true}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The query works but it's super ineffective since the index is not used. Based on my understanding, the DB engine has to do full collection scan and in each doc, check all the array elements.

Actually the collection has 75k records and every `approvers` array can hold up to 3 elements.

Is there any "trick" to make it more effective or the only option would be to change the data structure ?

Comment: unfortunately, like you expected, creating a separate collection of approvals+id is going to be the way to improve query time.

Comment: Are they always ordered? If so, you can check just the first item. You can even index just the first item in the array for this.

Comment: @nimrodserok they're not ordered unfortunately. The order of array elements reflects the order of "stages" a user's html form goes through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where separated collection is beneficial

Assuming above are projects, a different structure can be in place

```
//approvals
[{
  _id: ObjectId
  projectId: ObjectId // etc the _id in your code
  type: "one",
  details: "some stuff"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId
  projectId: ObjectId // etc the _id in your code
  type: "two",
  details: "some stuff"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId
  projectId: ObjectId // etc the _id in your code
  type: "three",
  details: "some stuff"
}]
```

Then you can can get all the projectId where type $ne ["one", "two"], before retrieving the related projects using $in. This should be achievable via aggregation too though I never tried.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Will see how often the clients will use the slow query. If it gets too annoying for them or the DB will be unacceptably throttled, I'll propose the structure change